# Rhythmbox cuts radio playback then raises Python error

Tags: rhythmbox

Scenario:
Stock Ubuntu 12.04 32bit in two machines; one is a laptop, one is a VirtualBox VM under WinXP, default Ubuntu install, both with Cairo-Dock (the problem appeared also under default Unity, though). Machines are one at home (cable-modem internet) and the other at the office (several internet connections, load-balanced).

Problem:
Rhythmbox refuses to stay connected to a radio. Anyone of the included radio lists, but I mostly "tune it" to Absolute Classic Rock. It starts playing for a couple of minutes, then cuts the audio, like it's buffering for a while, then resumes but at lower quality. Then, it cuts audio again and looks for a decoder. After a while searching an error box pops-up with the following text, no title:

```
Required plugin could not be found

Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: text/html decoder
```

The laptop had a clean reinstall; it had 10.04LTS (upgrade 10.04->12.04 gone awry) and its old Rhythmbox worked correctly. No cutouts at all, except under heavy network loads, but that was expected; and then it even tried two or three times at hi-quality (broadband) before going lo-quality (modem). Did not have the VM at the moment. In 12.04 it tries once, then steps quality down, then the plugin search, then the error appears.

Meanwhile, at the office, ancient WinAMP 2.95 works flawlessly in the WinXP host when tuned to the same radio... At the same time!

Is there a solution to this problem? Am I missing some very stupid config or setting? How can I debug where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround described here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1043039

"A workaround for this issue is to right-click the radio station, select properties, copy its URL, and then paste it back into a browser, download the playlist file, open it using a text editor, tweak it if desired, then open it using Rhythmbox -- a new radio station will appear, working this time."